# Default category when training a classification model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a text-classification model in Tensorflow 2.7.

I have great results when my text belongs to one of the categories, however in case that the text doesn't belong to any category, it just chooses a random category.

Is there any way to set a default category, without training one?

Comment: If you want your model to say `I don't know`, then you should use probabilistic models.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your clasificatoin model in some sort of backend, you could do some logic there that checks clasification's accuracy. You'd have to set a minimum accepted percentage, and mark anything under that percentage as 'none of your categories'.

Comment: I'm using Softmax, and it seems like my accuracy always adds up to one, and my accuracy goes to 90%+ on data.